# How to convert .jpeg image to .jif in java? (Exif TO JFIF)

Tags: java, type-conversion, jpeg

From customer i have request to send images in .JIF format (JFIF) . I have java aplication, but i coould not google anithing to topic of how to convert to that image type, i could even hardly google anithing to ".JIF" format itself.

EDITED :
Can somebody advice how to convert Exif image to JFIF in java ? And how to add coments to this JFIF image?
(tried to use jheader library sadly ended with nullpointer exception, not much more choices on google.)

Comment: is it JIF or JFIF(JPEG File Interchange format) I could not find any information about JIF and if this is the case then you need to update your question.

Comment: "Classic JPEG" *is* (a subset of) JIF + extra APPn markers. Normally, the files are in JFIF or Exif format. Are you sure you really need to do any conversion at all?

Comment: There is special request from customer that rejected our JPEG and requested JIF. But i wonder how can i get JIF from it (in java). Google is short to this topic .

Comment: @JiroMatchonson That's because no one really uses JIF (see the Wikipedia article on JPEG for details). Are you *sure* you don't want JFIF? Can you show a sample your client rejected? Can you ask him exactly what he means by "JIF"?

Comment: @JiroMatchonson Or do you actually mean [Jeff's Image Format](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Jeff%27s_Image_Format)? :-)

Comment: I also encountered that one :_D , but i guess not there are some converters with jpeg-jif (http://www.easy2convert.com/tiff2jpg/pro/) but really no info how to do it in java .

Comment: JFIF is "classic JPEG".

Comment: JFIF yes but not JIF?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_files

Comment: In response to haraldK and all of you (Tnx for all help!) i edited question to be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Converting Exif JPEGs to JFIF JPEGs:

If you don't mind losing some quality (due to lossy JPEG re-encoding), you can convert the image as simply as:

```
File inFile = ...;
File outFile = ...; // Feel free to use ".jif" as extension

if (!ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(inFile), "JPEG", outFile)) {
    System.err.println("Could not write JPEG format"); // Should never happen
}
```

This will work, because the default `JPEGImageWriter` plugin only supports JFIF format. And because we don't read the metadata, the old Exif information will just be lost. Doing it this way, will not allow you to add comments, however.

To add comments, you could still use standard ImageIO API, but we'll have to access the metadata, making the code more verbose. See [JPEG Metadata Format Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html) for more information on the metadata format. If you need to convert comments from the Exif metadata, please update your question to specific on that, as it requires further parsing of the meta data and extra support not currently in the ImageIO API.

```
File inFile = ...;
File outFile = ...; // Feel free to use ".jif" as extension

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inFile);

    ImageWriter jpegWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG").next(); // Should be a least one

    // To write comments, we need to add it to the metadata
    ImageWriteParam param = jpegWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    IIOMetadata metadata = jpegWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(image), param);
    IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0");
    IIOMetadataNode markerSequence = (IIOMetadataNode) root.getElementsByTagName("markerSequence").item(0); // Should be only one

    // Insert a "COM" marker, with our comment
    IIOMetadataNode com = new IIOMetadataNode("com");
    com.setAttribute("comment", "Hello JFIF!");
    markerSequence.appendChild(com);

    // Merge edited metadata 
    metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0", root);

    ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outFile);
    try {
        jpegWriter.setOutput(output);

        // Write image along with metadata
        jpegWriter.write(new IIOImage(image, null, metadata));
    }
    finally {
        output.close();
    }

    jpegWriter.dispose();
```

This way, we still re-encode the image in lossy JPEG, but we convert from Exif to JFIF and add comments.

Now, there is still another option, to do this completely lossless. But it does require a bit of a deeper understanding of the JIF segment structure, and how the Exif and JFIF formats work. Unfortunately, there's no standard Java API (that I know of) to do this, so you will have to roll your own. Feel free to use my [JPEG segment parsing code](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-metadata/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/metadata/jpeg) as a starting point. The [JHeader](http://jheader.sourceforge.net/) project you linked also looks very promising, but I don't have any experience with this library, so I can't provide any advice there.

Here's the basic idea:

1. Parse/skip the marker segments until the SOS (Start of Scan) segment (the data following the SOS will be the compressed image data).
2. Write the SOI marker (`0xffd8`)
3. Create an APP0/"JFIF" marker (I think you can just use defaults here, see [JFIF segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#JFIF_segment_format) for details). You can write 0, 0 for the thumb dimensions, and skip writing thumbnail data.
4. Add your COM segments with whatever comments you need (possibly extracted from the Exif metadata)
5. Write the SOF, DHT, DQT etc. standard segments as-is from the original stream (skip the APP1/"Exif" and other "custom" segments).
6. Write the SOS marker and the image data from the original stream

In theory, this should work. You might have some minor color space issues, as the Exif data might contain different color spaces (normally sRGB or AdobeRGB1998), while [JFIF doesn't have a defined color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#Color_space). If you need this add an APP2/"ICC_PROFILE" segment with the required profile (after step 3).

Good luck! :-)

---

Note: This is not a complete answer, but instead an attempt to clarify why you need to talk to your client, and figure out what is wrong with your JPEGs and what he actually means by "JIF".

First an foremost, *JPEG is not a file format*. [JPEG](http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg/index.html) is a still image compression standard. Part of this standard (usually referred to as "Annex B") is a description of an interchange format, sometimes referred to as JIF. The standard also specifies a full file format known as SPIFF, but this format is not very widespread (and I don't think this is what you want).

The files you find everywhere, referred to as "JPEG files" (and I assume this is what you refer to as "Classic JPEG"), is usually in one of two slightly different flavors of basically the same file format:

The most basic format is JFIF. This format starts with a SOI marker, immediately followed by an APP0 marker with "JFIF" (null-terminated) as its identifier. According to the [original JFIF specification](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf) "**The JPEG File Interchange Format is entirely compatible with the standard JPEG interchange format;** the only additional requirement is the mandatory presence of the APP0 marker right after the SOI marker." (this part is left out of the [ITU](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.871-201105-I/en) and ISO versions of the specification, but still applies). Put simply, JFIF constrains the JPEG data to be 1 or 3 components, encoded as either Y or YCbCr, and highly recommends baseline DCT, Huffman coded compression.

The other common format is [Exif](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf). This format starts with a SOI marker, immediately followed by an APP1 marker with "Exif" (null-terminated) as its identifier. This format is developed by the digital camera manufacturers, and allows much richer meta data to be recorded within the file (in the form of a TIFF meta data structure). From what I understand, Exif constrains the JPEG data to be 3 components, encoded as YCbCr, using baseline DCT, Huffman coded compression (the last part may be just a an interoperability recommendation, the language in the spec is a little hard to read...).

Both of these formats contains the same "segment" layout and the image data is compatible, but still they are mutually exclusive, due to the requirement of having "their" marker as the first segment in the stream (because of this, also a "third" format exists, which is a JFIF for compatibility, but still contains an Exif segment for richer meta data).

Yet another family of "JPEG files" lacks both JFIF and Exif markers, but still follows the same segment layout, with SOI, APPn markers, SOF, DHT, DQT, SOS and EOI markers, as described in "Annex B" (JIF). Most decoders will decode these images as well.

**TL;DR: To summarize, what all the "JPEG" file formats have in common, is that they use JPEG compression, and follows the JIF structure. Because of this, it is somewhat hard to understand what someone means by "convert classic JPEG to JIF".**

**"Classic JPEG" *is* JIF.**

Comment: Got response from client. And most likely what you say is true. Images what i have to create are *.jif by exptension, but are indeed JFIF. From our devices we got Exif images. So true question behind this topic is :
"How to convert Exif image to JFIF image in java."
"And how to add comments to them."
Example of headers in both images :
Exif image : "ÿØÿá^B^@Exif^@^@II*^@^H^@^@^@..."
jif/JFIF needed :  ÿØÿà^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^A^@..."
So "Exif to JFIF" in java, i could not google anithing reasonable, just http://jheader.sourceforge.net/ which sadly does not work (nullpointerException).

Comment: Finnaly got response and seems all conversted images and comments are fine, thank You very much! , accepted as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to read that image then you must write that image into the dimensions and format you want.
You must use **ImageIO** class and **BufferedReader** to read images
To write them use **Graphics2D** class
Replace format name with **jif**

```
 File inputFile = new File(inputImagePath);
    BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

    // creates output image
    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth,
            scaledHeight, inputImage.getType());

    // scales the input image to the output image
    Graphics2D g2d = outputImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    // extracts extension of output file
    String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath
            .lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

    // writes to output file
    ImageIO.write(outputImage, formatName, new File(outputImagePath));
```

Comment: Hello wehere exactly do i set .JIF format to new image ? Or what part of code changes this image to JIF ? Does BufferedImage support that type?

Comment: read the last line 
ImageIO.write(outputImage ,"jif",new File(outputImagePath));

Comment: @JiroMatchonson i have tested that code and it works fine on png , jpeg and other standard formats of image.. but i think that windows can't recognize this format , you need to have some extra third party tool that can open **.jif**.
However you can download this tool from [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xnview.com%2F&ei=s7QCVfi2CZChugT7i4HwAg&usg=AFQjCNF1jCka55Hpo8bRlSkEwYdDAQDEAQ&sig2=9fiolROyD0nX8cEMigOwnA&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E)

Comment: Oh thatsounds cool, tnx much for effort, mainly i need it for images to be in right valid .jif type so devices of our customer can recognise them (they will not recognise classic jpeg images just .jif ones). Tnx very much for effort ill try your implementations and mark as right answer if all goes well :)

Comment: Please note that ` ImageIO.write(...)` does not throw an exception if the format is not supported, instead it returns `false`. You should check this return value. I am sure `ImageIO` does *NOT* support any format called "jif".

Comment: @haraldK yeah i think it's Jeff's Image Format